# Build .doc file from iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have an iPhone app with a normal form (text input fields). I would like to take the text from those inputs and build a Word file (.doc) so I can email it.

I already can build a .txt file and email it, but I don't know where to start for word files. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.doc is a proprietary Microsoft format. I'm not positive that you'll truly be able to build a .doc file, especially on an Apple platform.

However, .docx is an approved standard based on XML so you should be able to find a spec sheet somewhere.